# Odd printing / print preview

Tags: bugs, printing

**Bug introduced in 12.2 or earlier and fixed in 12.3**

---

What's is going on here with the print display in my Mathematica? Has anyone else seen this behavior? The notebook looks completely normal in the frontend display.

[image: garbled print output]

This mess appears in the print output, print preview, and also when I attempt to save as pdf.

I'm running a stock install:

```
$Version
(* "12.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)" *)
```

- OS:      GNU/Linux (x86_64)
- Kernel:  4.19.0-13-amd64
- Distro:  Debian stable (Debian 4.19.160-2, 2020-11-28)

---

Addendum: This appears to be fixed in 12.3

Comment: You might want to contact Wolfram with steps to reproduce this problem, and mention the details of your system (such as OS and OS version).

Comment: Can you add more details about your system (Linux distro, version, etc.)? Then we can mark this as a bug and indicate that it was fixed in the standard bug header.